# does a List<> when changed change all other references to the LIst<>?

Tags: java, list, reference

As we all know in Java if you change a object 'everyone' that has a reference to that object also changes like in the following example.

```
List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
mainList.add("a");
mainList.add("c");
mainList.add("b");
mainList.add("d");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainList.toArray(new String[mainList.size()]))); // randomly ordered strings [a, c, b, d]

List<String> referencedList = mainList;// referencedList contains the same unordered strings [a, c, b, d]

Collections.sort(mainList);// mainList is sorted [a, b, c, d]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(referencedList.toArray(new String[ referencedList.size()]))); // the referenced list is also sorted
```

Is there any way to get a List<> that only the objects within are updated across all of the arrays but the referenced arrays stay unsorted?

Comment: You don't have to use `List->toArray->toString` combo. Just use `toString` from `List` itself if you want to print its content in form `[element1, element2, ..., elementN]`. So use `System.out.println(mainList);` instead of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainList.toArray(new String[mainList.size()])));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a shallow clone, e.g.

```
List<String> referencedStrings = new ArrayList<>(referencedStrings);
```

That will take a copy of the existing list - but as the list only contains references, any changes to the objects those references refer to will be visible via both lists. (Not that you could change the contents of `String` objects anyway, mind you...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that referencedList hold the same reference like mainList.
The key is to create a copy of the content of mainList.

You can iterate over mainList like

```
List<String> referencedList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s: mainList){
    referenced.add(s);
}
//sort mainList
```

Both lists will hold the same references but mainList is sorted.

Or just use the ArrayList(List list) constructor as Jon Skeet pointed out.

Now you can sort the mainList because it only changes the list itself but not its content.

Answer (score 0):

No need to sort the list elements.Now the below code shows the elements and sequence of mainlist.

```
List<String> mainList = new ArrayList<String>();
mainList.add("a");
mainList.add("c");
mainList.add("b");
mainList.add("d");

// randomly ordered strings [a, c, b, d]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainList.toArray(new String[mainList.size()])));
// referencedList contains the same unordered strings [a, c, b, d]
List<String> referencedList = mainList;
// the referenced list is also sorted
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(referencedList.toArray(new String[ referencedList.size()])));
```

thanks.